# Rule to save a node based on fetched entity throws EntityMalformedException when the field is empty

Tags: 7, rules

So I have a rule that attempts to fetch a node using fetch entity by property, and re-save it with a new author if a user field value matches a node field value upon user login.

It works just fine unless it can't find a match, in which case I get the following error:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type
>   node. in entity_extract_ids()

I'm kind of surprised I get this error if the value doesn't exist, but now I need a workaround.

Is there some condition I can add here to prevent the error, or am I looking at removing the "fetch entity by property", and adding a `db_query()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wound up writing code to fetch the entity:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'my_content_type')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_my_field', 'value', $some_value, '=')
  ->range(0, 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```

I then wound up using `$result` to update the target node's author:

```
if($result) {
  $eid=current($result['node']);
  $node = node_load($eid->nid);
  $node->uid = $account->uid;
  node_save($node);
}
```

I wonder if there's a method to query the database for a single entity? That would save the "hassle" of adding a range, then having to extract the desired value from the `$result` array.